# GetInvocationList of an event in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, delegates

I am trying to learn some WCF principles by following an example of a WCF application (from Sacha Barber).

Now I would like to convert the following function into VB.NET

```
private void BroadcastMessage(ChatEventArgs e)
{

    ChatEventHandler temp = ChatEvent;

    if (temp != null)
    {
        foreach (ChatEventHandler handler in temp.GetInvocationList())
        {
            handler.BeginInvoke(this, e, new AsyncCallback(EndAsync), null);
        }
    }
}
```

but I have some problems, because the following code is not accepted by the compiler

```
Private Sub BroadcastMessage(ByVal e As ChatEventArgs)

    Dim handlers As EventHandler(Of ChatEventArgs) = ChatEvent

    If handlers IsNot Nothing Then

        For Each handler As EventHandler(Of ChatEventArgs) In handlers.GetInvocationList()

            handler.BeginInvoke(Me, e, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf EndAsync), Nothing)

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

it says

> Public Shared Event ChatEvent(sender
>   As Object, e As ChatEventArgs)' is an
>   event, and cannot be called directly

Coming to the point, **is it then possible in VB.NET get the handlers linked to a certain event in some other way?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use ChatEventEvent   (or *EventName*Event)

It won't show up in intellisense, but the members of it will.

VB.NET creates a variable behind the scenes, to hide the complexity from the coder...

This is only available in the class that declares the event (or perhaps its descendants)

Comment: Just bear in mind that you're using an undocumented member on your class, and (unless I'm mistaken) this naming policy is not guaranteed to stay the same in future compiler versions.

Comment: @Adam - Yeah, definitely undocumented, as far as I've seen, but I can't see them changing it unless they have some reason to, or at least provide an alternative.  In any case, it is the only way you can do it currently, without handling all of the event stuff on your own, as in your example.  Yours will still work if they change it, but I would rather save that work given the likelihood that it will change.

Answer (score 7):

You're likely trying to write this code in a class that is a descendant of the class that declares the `ChatEvent` event. This can't be done, as events can only be treated as variables (including invoking them) in the class that declares them. This is because the `event` keyword actually indicates to the compiler that it needs to perform some behind-the-scenes transformations.

**What Happens**

Consider this declaration:

```
Public Event MyEvent as EventHandler
```

Simple enough, right? What this actually does, however, is this (you just don't see it)

```
Private compilerGeneratedName as EventHandler

Public Event MyEvent as EventHandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value as EventHandler)
        compilerGeneratedName += value
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value as EventHandler)
        compilerGeneratedName -= value
    End RemoveHandler
    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
        compilerGeneratedName.Invoke(sender, e)
    End RaiseEvent
End Event
```

And when you invoke the event:

```
RaiseEvent MyEvent(Me, EventArgs.Emtpy)
```

It actually calls the code in the `RaiseEvent` block.

**Edit**

If events in VB.NET can't be treated as variables *anywhere* (they can be treated as variables in the declaring class in C#, which is why your C# example compiles), then you'll have to explicitly implement the event yourself. See the [MSDN page on the Event statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hwhs172.aspx) for more information on how to do that. To make a long story short, you're going to want some way to store multiple event handlers (or use a single event handler along with `GetInvocationList`, as you're trying to do now). In your `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` code blocks you'll add to and remove from the list of event handlers (respectively).

You could use something like this:

```
Private myEventList as New List(Of EventHandler)

Public Custom Event MyEvent as EventHandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value as EventHandler)
        myEventList.Add(value)
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value as EventHandler)
        myEventList.Remove(value)
    End RemoveHandler
    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
        For Each evt in myEventList
           evt.BeginInvoke(sender, e, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf EndAsync), Nothing)
        Next
    EndRaiseEvent
End Event
```

So now, if you call

```
RaiseEvent MyEvent(Me, EventArgs.Emtpy)
```

It will raise the event in the fashion you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't think is my case. 
My class is called ChatService and it declares both the Shared Event ChatEvent and the Sub BroadcastMessage, where I am trying to get the InvocationList of ChatEvent.

Comment: in the above first example, compilerGeneratedName is *always* the event name followed by the word "Event", so, ChatEventEvent, in this case.

Comment: thanks for the info, they could be helpful, and for the effort

@Rick
Yeah! That made the trick for me

Comment: I had no idea you could put all of that into an event.  Looks almost like a property.  But it's not.